# Target class [Admin\FirstController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I face a problem while trying to create a router under namespace "Instructor" as per the image below:

[Route in instructor page in routes file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZlDz.png)

and the method under the namespace Instructor in the controller is:

[method inside the controller file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct2PD.png)

it keeps giving me the following error when running the route:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeSA5.png)

can anyone help me solve this issue as I am new to larevel so I am not a pro in defining the packages and dependencies.

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your problem exactly, but when these strange errors happen, I always run (just to be sure): `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 8, you can simply do the following in your route file:

```php
Route::get('instructors', [\App\Http\Controllers\Instructor\FirstController::class, 'showUserName']);
```

Or with quotes:

```php
Route::get('instructors', ['\App\Http\Controllers\Instructor\FirstController', 'showUserName']);
```

Or with `use` statement:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Instructor\FirstController;

Route::get('instructors', [FirstController::class, 'showUserName']);
```

You can then have all your `use` statements at the top. Most IDE can automatically hide them so you have a clean route file.

Comment: Check the end, I quickly updated my answer, `::class` was missing at the end, but you seem to have read it before, sorry!

Comment: it worked with this structure : 
Route::get('instructors',' [\App\Http\Controllers\Instructor\FirstController', 'showUserName']);

THANK YOU so much

Comment: Yes you can do both, either `'\App\Http\Controllers\Instructor\FirstController'` or without quotes: `\App\Http\Controllers\Instructor\FirstController::class` (note the `::class` at the end). The second approach has the benefit of allowing to make it shorter by using a `use` statement. I'll update my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8 you can do:

```
Route::get('your-route', [App\Http\Controllers\Instructor\YourController::class, 'methodName']);
```

Or you can uncomment following line in RouteServiceProvider

```
// protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```